# ESLint Rule to restrict from importing full SDKs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, require, rules

In my project, developers import full SDKs instead of only specific modules.

For example:

```
const CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = require('aws-sdk');
```

Here^ developer wants to use CognitoIdentityServiceProvider, so they should only import CognitoIdentityServiceProvider like below:

```
const CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = require('aws-sdk/clients/cognitoidentityserviceprovider');
```

This gets missed in code reviews as well. I want to add some eslint rules to restrict importing full SDKs.

Tried `"no-restricted-imports": ["error", "aws-sdk"]` but this does not work with require statements.

Comment: How would a lint rule know the difference between `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = require('aws-sdk');` (which you apparently don't want) and `const got = require('got');` which is perfectly reasonable for a third party module?  I don't know how a lint rule could know whether a top level import is just fine or not?

Comment: Since you tagged the question as [[tag:ES6]], how about you switch to `import` declarations?

Comment: @jfriend00 If somehow we can provide list of import so that rule should not accept those specific import if its an exact match?

Comment: @Bergi its a plan to move to import declarations soon in the future. For now need some hack for the require declaration.

Comment: You can do a lot with the [no-restricted-syntax rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax) and a selector to match that expression

Answer (score 0):

There is the rule [`no-restricted-modules`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-modules) which acts as a counterpart to `no-restricted-imports` (it's even mentioned in the respective [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-imports)). So you could configure the rule like this:

```json
"no-restricted-modules": ["error", "aws-sdk"]
```

Anyway, the built-in rule is deprecated and it's recommended to use the rule in eslint-plugin-node: [`node/no-restricted-require`](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node/blob/master/docs/rules/no-restricted-require.md). To use the plugin rule, first install `eslint-plugin-node`:

```
npm install -D eslint-plugin-node
```

Then, in the ESLint configuration, declare the plugin and configure the rule (note the different configuration):

```json
{
  ...
  "plugins": ["node"],
  "rules": {
    "node/no-restricted-require":
    [
      "error",
      [
        {
          "name": "aws-sdk",
          "message": "Please, require a more specific module."
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

Finally, I would note that `eslint-plugin-node` has been unmaintained for over one year today, so you may want to use [`eslint-plugin-n`](https://github.com/eslint-community/eslint-plugin-n) instead.